# Comparando Datas em string, utilizando SQLite e NHibernate

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

Eu estou usando SQLite e NHIbernate, e estou guardando no meu banco as `Datas` como `String` no SQLite, pois não é possível armazenar datas no mesmo. Tudo tava indo ok, mas eu precisei comparar datas para imprimir um relatório. Agora, não consigo fazer essa comparação, pois está em `string`, e não consigo converter para `Date` no LINQ/Lambda.

Tentei o seguinte:

```
var dataInicial = DateTime.Parse(_DataInicial);
var dataFinal = DateTime.Parse(_DataFinal);
return session.QueryOver<Locacoes>()
     .Where(c => DateTime.Parse(c.DataInicial) >= dataInicial )
     .Where(c => DateTime.Parse(c.DataFinal) <= dataFinal).List();
```

Mas da uma `Exception` no primeiro `Where`:

> "A variavel 'c' do tipe 'Locacoes' é referenciada no escopo '', mas não foi definida".

Não sei se esse é o problema, mas eu gostaria mesmo como eu posso comparar duas datas no NHibernate, sendo que elas estão em `string` pois gravadas em SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos, mas eu tive que modificar o método da pesquisa.

Vou ter que alterar o formato da minha data, pois estava em "31/07/2016" para "20160731".

e ficou dessa maneira:

```
            string dataInicial = "'20100604'";
            var query = "SELECT * from Clientes as c where c.Data >= " + dataInicial;
            var lista = session.CreateSQLQuery(query).List();
```